# VBA: Select last cell in column range and copy cells in worksheet

Tags: vba

I have several columns and I am trying to copy the very last cell of each column into one column (in another worksheet).

This is my code that didn't work (I am looping through rows and columns):

```
 Sub lastcell()

 Dim lRow As Long
Dim lCol As Long

Dim i As Long


Worksheets("input").Select

 With Worksheets("input")
 Worksheets("output").Cells.ClearContents

 lCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

 Set ColRange = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(5, lCol))

For Each ccol In ColRange
  lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, ccol).End(xlUp).Rows.Count

   For i = 2 To 6
    Worksheets("output").Cells(i, 1) = .Cells(lRow, ccol)

 Next i
Next ccol


End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have one too many loops.

The `lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, ccol).End(xlUp).Rows.Count` should end with `Row` not `.Rows.Count`

Also with `Set ColRange = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(5, lCol))` you are going to loop through each column 5 times.  The `5` should be a `1`

There is no need to acivate or select the input sheet at the beginning of the code.

ccol should be declared

```
Sub lastcell()

Dim lRow As Long
Dim lCol As Long
Dim ccol as Range
Dim i As Long   

With Worksheets("input")
    Worksheets("output").Cells.ClearContents
    lCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    Set colrange = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, lCol))
    i = 1
    For Each ccol In colrange
        lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, ccol.Column).End(xlUp).Row
        Worksheets("output").Cells(i, 1).Value = .Cells(lRow, ccol.Column).Value
        i = i + 1
    Next ccol


End With

End Sub
```

---

We can simplify it even further with a simple for loop:

```
Sub lastcell()

Dim lRow As Long
Dim lCol As Long
Dim i As Long

With Worksheets("input")
    Worksheets("output").Cells.ClearContents
    lCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    For i = 1 To lCol
        lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row
        Worksheets("output").Cells(i, 1).Value = .Cells(lRow, i).Value
    Next i

End With
```

---

Just for an FYI, this can also be done with a formula.

In your first cell on the output sheet put this formula:

```
=INDEX(input!A:Z,MAX(IFERROR(MATCH("ZZZ",INDEX(input!A:Z,0,ROW(1:1))),0),IFERROR(MATCH(1E+99,INDEX(input!A:Z,0,ROW(1:1))),0)),ROW(1:1))
```

And then copy/drag the formula down till you get `0`s